What is the purpose of chloromercuration of HgOAc group?
In some reactions using $\ce{Hg(OAc)_2}$, I saw some cases that convert $\ce{-HgOAc}$ group into $\ce{-HgCl}$ group by adding $\ce{NaCl}$. Below is one example, the synthesis of (+)-preussin.

Mercury(II) acetate page of Wikipedia also explains this chloromercuration reaction. But why? Are there any advantages of $\ce{-HgCl}$ group over $\ce{-HgOAc}$ group in the synthesis?

Compound 5 isn't necessarily the last step in the sequence of reactions.  What is/are compound/compounds 6 (, and  7, etc.) in the publication you extract the reaction scheme?  They could explain why this was the choice of the authors. (By the way, in addition to credit to whom credit is due, quote the reference you refer to -- e.g., book title, doi of journal article -- to provide context of your question, attract readers to your question, etc.)

If I remember correctly (IIRC), RHgCl compounds are more readily isolated than RHgOAc species, presumably by crystallization.
